# ¿como guardar fecha en una BD de postgres?

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2017

Necesito guardar la fecha en la BD pero no se como y he intentado pero no me dice que el SP no existe

este es el codigo con el que he intentado

```
  cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("fun_factura", conexion, transaccion);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Transaction = transaccion;

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_codigofactura", Convert.ToInt32(codigofactura.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fecha.Text).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_cliente", Convert.ToString(cliente.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_proveedor", Convert.ToString(proveedor.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

este es el SP

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_factura(
f_codigofactura integer,
f_cliente character varying,
f_proveedor character varying,
f_total integer,
f_fecha date) 

RETURNS integer AS $BODY$
```

Comment: ¿Has creado el SP?

Comment: si , ya lo agrege  a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en mandarle datetime a un date de postgres.
Inténtelo de esta forma, me parece que usted esta llamando una función no un sp y la función no esta haciendo el insert:

Modifique primero la función en la bd como sigue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun_factura(
f_codigofactura integer,
f_cliente character varying,
f_proveedor character varying,
f_total integer,
f_fecha timestamp)
 RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $$
begin
insert into tienda(campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4,campo5) values(f_codigofactura,f_cliente,f_proveedor,f_total   );
end;
$$;



cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select public.fun_factura(@f_codigofactura,@f_fecha,@f_cliente,@f_proveedor,@f_total,f_fecha )", conexion);



            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f_codigofactura", Convert.ToInt32(codigofactura.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f_fecha", Convert.ToDateTime(fecha.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f_cliente", Convert.ToString(cliente.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f_proveedor", Convert.ToString(proveedor.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f_total", Convert.ToInt32(total.Text));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Cambie el / por - Por alguna razón que desconozco no acepta el / solo el -  y otra cosa no recuerdo si los parámetros son con @ o con ? entonces si no le sirve con @ pruebe con ?

Como puede ver mi respuesta le quita la funcionalidad de transacción a la operación. Si lo que quiere es evitar problemas de concurrencia yo le recomiendo bloquear la tabla de la siguiente forma: `BEGIN;LOCK TABLE consecutivo in share mode;{operación (insert,select,update u otra)};COMMIT;ROLLBACK;`

Comment: nada, no me ha funcionado me sigue diciendo que la función no existe

Comment: Pues claro porque la función que esta llamando en ninguna parte hace un insert.

Comment: Modifique la función para que haga el insert o haga el insert directamente de el código. Como se llama la tabla donde quiere hacer el insert?

Comment: la tabla se llama tienda

Comment: Y los campos de la tabla como se llaman

Comment: son los mismos que estan hay en el codigo

Comment: Modifique la función de la bd según la modificación que hice. Pongale bien los nombres de los campos en el insert

Comment: Revise bien los últimos cambios. Hice cambios en la función de la bd y en el código.